# Shopware 6 - Field validation in plugin configuration not working

Tags: plugins, shopware6

I have added below code in `config.xml` for plugin validation but its by passing.
Blank values are being saved.

Although asterisk (*) is showing on each input field.

I tried to change the `<required>1</required>` to `<required>true</required>` but that also not helps.

```
<card><input-field type="text">
        <name>userName</name>
        <label>Username</label>
        <label lang="de-DE">Nutzername</label>
        <required>1</required>
    </input-field>

    <input-field type="text">
        <name>password</name>
        <label>Password</label>
        <label lang="de-DE">Passwort</label>
        <required>1</required>
    </input-field></card>
```

Does any one helps me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem and we already got a [ticket](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-6598) for that.

Comment: plus one..  thanks for the answer.. i was trying to build the separate component otherwise.

Comment: Building your own vue-js module would be the best solution to that.